# What are the Christian doctrines denied by the Igreja Maná (Mana Church), if any?

Tags: church-local, apostles

In the city where I live there's a church called [Mana Church](http://www.igrejamana.com/int/inicial3_linguas.php?lang=eng).

I know they venerate (not to the level of God) the founder, Jorge Tadeu.

This gives me chills because of Luke 4:8 [KJV]

> And Jesus answered and said unto him, Get thee behind me, Satan: for
>   it is written, Thou shalt worship the Lord thy God, and him only shalt
>   thou serve.

In fact, they call this person Apostle. Without providing clarity, this term is misleading people into believing Jorge Tadeu is at the same level of authority as "the twelve" (Matthew 26:14; John 6:67, 20:24; 1 Corinthians 15:5) and [we know](https://carm.org/apostles-today)

> a true apostle in the New
>   Testament style is no longer possible because it would require that
>   the person had been with Christ and/or have seen the risen Lord.

Can't stop thinking if there are any christian doctrines they deny? If yes, which ones? (Psalms 11:3)

> If the foundations be destroyed, what can the righteous do?

Comment: Note that CARM is literally the thoughts on one individual. Most Protestants won't agree with everything he writes, let alone all the other Christians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Portuguese Wikipedia page](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&u=https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Igreja_Man%25C3%25A1) they look like a fairly typical Pentecostal/charismatic church. Whether that's a denial of Christian doctrine depends on you.

Personally I do think that teaching that we can all expect great prosperity in this life is a false gospel, and that to expect all Christians to speak in tongues is a denial of 1 Corinthians 12:4-31, but I'm not certain this church actually teaches those things, they could teach softer more acceptable versions.

As to calling their founder an Apostle, that's not uncommon in Pentecostalism, or Christianity more broadly. That webpage you found, CARM, is the work on one individual and of course lots of people would disagree with that criteria for Apostlehood. As apostle means "one who is sent" I think there's a very good case for calling Christian missionaries "apostles". Either way, it's not very noteworthy.

All in all, it looks like a pretty typical Pentecostal church. I can't see any major warning signs.

Comment: in the one here there's a moment of the weekly gathering, everyone present has to start to "speak in tongues" (like you make reference to). All in all, do you think it's part of the [New Apostolic Reformation](https://www.gotquestions.org/New-Apostolic-Reformation.html)?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres Yeah that sounds likely, though I don't think that page really justifies its judgement. [Wikipedia looks more neutral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Apostolic_Reformation). I'm still not really seeing anything that suggests it's markedly outside what's common in other pentecostal churches.

Comment: Yes sure, the definition of apostle meaning messenger is in the bible - 1 Kings 14:6; Isaiah 18:2; John 13:16; 2 Corinthians 8:23; Philippians 2:25. And sure, they indeed look pentecostal, believing speaking tongues to be a sign of spiritual validity, which is something, as you say, Paul had to fight in Corinth.

Comment: I believe that definition provided in CARM is to protect against current claims of continuity of scriptures, doctrinal authority at church and canonical authority.